# jQueryUI autocomplete with clickable links?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This was my first time using jQueryUI autocomplete, I managed to get it working, there is just one more functionality that our client needs, i.e to have clickable categories in the search suggestions.

For example, look at this image:

[image]

Its from newegg website, When I search "nvidia", a suggestion list populates, besides just the item name the category it lies in is also shown but the category appears as a text and not link(i.e category itself is not clickable). I do the same, I return the search results from a service running on the server and populate the suggestions. I don't need to return links, I can just split the returned string at "in" to get the "category" and then produce the link as
 `<a href="someinternalpage.aspx?cat=category">Category</a>` (This code is just for quick Idea) . But now comes the main problem, how do I populate the suggestions with the above clickable link?

Any help would be most welcomed.

Answer (score 3):

I would tap into the `select` event that autocomplete exposes and set `window.location` to the proper URL:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    var category = $.trim(ui.item.value.split("in")[1])
        , url = "someinternalpage.aspx?cat=" + category;

    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what I want is that not the whole list but only when someone clicks whatever follows after "in", be he redirected.

Comment: @AshwinSingh: Could you show the code you currently have? How are you displaying the categories?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker The jsfiddle link doesn't exists. Could up update your answer.

Comment: @user3731784: Thanks for the heads up, I'll try to get a working link up later today.

Answer (score 0):

Based simply on the demo page for the autocomplete, it seems that the suggestions are targetable.

Meaning, I would register a click function on them to get their content, and then use jQuery to either redirect the window using the correct URL pathing for the search (so something like http://domain.com/search=+content) or use javascript itself to submit the form.

The javascript submit is pretty detailed here http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Without any code, that is how I would address the issue.